# Change each text after 4 second and each image after 2 second

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically first two images(image1, image2) from array depend on first string(String1) from array. and other two images on String2, so i want string1 change after 4 second but in this time two images being change that relates string1 and so on for string2 and their images.

```
<script>
var text = ["String1", "String2"];
var backgroundImg=["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"]
var counter = 0;
var currentPos = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("animated-text");
var elembg = document.getElementById("animated-background");
var inst = setInterval(change, 4000);
var bginst = setInterval(changeImage, 2000);

function change() {
  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
   
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
    // clearInterval(inst); // uncomment this if you want to stop refreshing after one cycle
  }
}

function changeImage() {   
        if (++currentPos >= backgroundImg.length){
        currentPos = 0;
        }
        elembg.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[currentPos]+"')";
}  
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress development (even if this is happening in a WordPress-powered site). You should post it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: you never stated the question, are you asking what's wrong with the code? I can't see anything WordPress related here, if you're asking a general javascript question it should go on stackoverflow instead

Comment: Yeah, its general question but for the wordpress